# Magento XMLRPC Call failing with "Calling parameters do not match signature"

Tags: c#, magento, xml-rpc

I would like to use the Function "catalog.list" from Magento API (Link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html )

My calling parameter looks like this:

```
Product.List("mydomain.com/api/xmlrpc", "3345dd3eedc3deadbeef", new object[] { XMLFilter },StoreViewIDAsString);
```

when using this Function with Parameter "StoreViewIDAsString" it response with:

```
623 : Calling parameters do not match signature
```

My proxy looks like this:

```
public static Product[] List(string apiUrl, string sessionId, object[] args, string store_view)
{
   IProduct prox = (IProduct)XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(typeof(IProduct));
   prox.Url = apiUrl;
   return prox.List(sessionId, _catalog_product_list, args,store_view);
}

[XmlRpcMethod("call")]
Product[] List(string sessionId, string method, object[] args,string store_view);
```

I'm using Ez.LLC's Magento API Wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into this when building a custom NodeJs API XMLRPC wrapper for Magento. Specifically for the catalog_category.assignedProducts resource.

The docs http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.assignedProducts.html ask for an integer value category id, but it really likes to get an array of an integer value category id.

I turned this:

```
...
APIClient.methodCall('call',
        [sessionId, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts', 8] ...
```

Into this:

```
...
APIClient.methodCall('call',
        [sessionId, 'catalog_category.assignedProducts', [8] ] ...
```

and eliminated that error.